# Jasper font extensions Tomcat 8/JDK 8

Tags: java, java-8, jasper-reports, tomcat8

I have been using Jasper for about 5 years and have been using font extensions just fine in all that time on Tomcat 6 and 7 with both OpenJDK 7 and Oracle JDK 7 with various versions of Jasper, the most recent being 5.1.0. All of this deployed to the same Ubuntu server running 12.04.

I have recently deployed the same application to Tomcat 8 with Oracle JDK 8 and Jasper 5.6.1, also on the same server. I am using the same fonts jar I created 4-5 years ago, and it just doesn't work. I don't see any error messages about missing fonts but it is apparently not finding or loading the fonts. If I deploy the exact same war file to a Tomcat 7 instance on the same server using Oracle JDK 7 it works just fine.

I plan on adding another instance of Tomcat 7 using JDK 8 and seeing what I get, but before I started swapping out all the pieces until I find the answer I was hoping someone might already have seen/conquered this issue.

Comment: We can just guess why your font-extension will not work, multiple extensions in classpath for example?. We would need information on how to reproduce it, but this does not seem easy to include in a SO question

Comment: @PetterFriberg I understand, not much to go on, but as I said it's just worked and does still work as expected on the older server instances, just hoping someone else has stumbled on this before...

Comment: I would check libs in classpath  and properties file in classpath for other  jasperreports_extension.properties